# check if a value exist in an array php do while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if a value exist in a do while loop after putting it into an array.

i.e.

```
<?php
$query_tags = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM units ");
//getting values from db

$list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_tags)) {
   $list[] =  $row['code'];
}

$mylist = '[' . implode(',', $list) . ']'

echo $mylist;
//result will look like this: [kis,his,mat,geo]
?>
```

Now i want to check if the word kis exist in the list above

I have tried

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists("kis",$list))
  {
  echo "Key exists!";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Key does not exist!";
  }

  ?>
```

Doesn't work. any help on this? or any other better approach

Comment: Well you printed out the values of your array and then you checked if a key exists. So you probably want to check if you have that value in your array with `in_array()`

Comment: @Rizier123 the question might have same answer for it to be duplicate but i dont see it as a duplicate to that question

Comment: You ask how you can check if a value exists in an array and the duplicate exactly shows you how to do that.

Comment: @Rizier123 You where to quick to mark it as duplicate now i cant get more solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your condition to `if (in_array("kis",$list))` 
because previously you were searching in array by key, instead of value.

Answer (score 1):

In your array, "`kis`" is a `value` not `key`. Your keys are 0,1,2,3

You should use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) PHP function. It will check value.

```
if (in_array("kis",$list)){
  echo "Value exists!";
}
else  {
  echo "Value does not exist!";
}
```

Comment: ravi i believe you will have to change `$list,["kis"]` to `"kis",$list` since i is bringing an error.

Comment: @krushiovida: ohh!! my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.